# SQL: ORDER BY using a substring within a specific column... possible?

Tags: sql, sorting, substring

I have a database whose columns are npID, title, URL, and issue.

Here is an example of two years' entries:

```
npID               title               URL               issue
88                 EMR Newsletter      a.com             2010 Third_Quarter
89                 EMR Newsletter      b.com             2010 Second_Quarter
43                 EMR Newsletter      c.com             2010 First_Quarter
47                 EMR Newsletter      d.com             2009 Winter
45                 EMR Newsletter      e.com             2009 Summer
46                 EMR Newsletter      f.com             2009 Spring
44                 EMR Newsletter      g.com             2009 Fall
```

What I would like to do is be able to sort the results based on substrings within the "issue" column.  However, until 2010, the client used seasons as the header and in 2010, they started using quarters.  Is there a way in the "ORDER BY" I can provide a list of words to sort by if/when they're found anywhere in the "issue" value?

I would like the end result to be something like this:

```
npID               title               URL               issue
43                 EMR Newsletter      c.com             2010 First_Quarter
89                 EMR Newsletter      b.com             2010 Second_Quarter
88                 EMR Newsletter      a.com             2010 Third_Quarter
47                 EMR Newsletter      d.com             2009 Winter
45                 EMR Newsletter      e.com             2009 Summer
46                 EMR Newsletter      f.com             2009 Spring
44                 EMR Newsletter      g.com             2009 Fall
```

Comment: I don't understand you wanting to sort 2009 entries as Winter->Summer->Spring->Fall. What's up with that?

Comment: It's what the client wants... I don't ask questions

Comment: Gotchya.. thought it was a typo or something.

Comment: The sort order in the example is messed up.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can put a `CASE` statement in the `ORDER BY` to accomplish this. A better route would be to change the application and table to actually store this relevant data in columns where it belongs when you have the development time to do that.

```
ORDER BY
    CAST(SUBSTRING(issue, 1, 4) AS INT) DESC,  -- Year
    CASE
        WHEN issue LIKE '%First_Quarter' OR issue LIKE '%Winter' THEN 1
        WHEN issue LIKE '%Second_Quarter' OR issue LIKE '%Spring' THEN 2
        WHEN issue LIKE '%Third_Quarter' OR issue LIKE '%Summer' THEN 3
        WHEN issue LIKE '%Fourth_Quarter' OR issue LIKE '%Fall' THEN 4
    END
```

Order the seasons however you want. You could also order them in a specific way (Q1 followed by Spring, followed by Q2, etc.) by adjusting the `CASE` statement.

Comment: Works - but I'm getting the `2009 ....`  stuff before the `2010 ....` issues.....

Comment: should be `substring(issue,1,4) desc),`

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I've changed the answer appropriately

Answer (score 10):

#### Standard SQL

Try a [`CASE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE) statement in the `ORDER BY`:

```sql
SELECT npID, title, URL, issue
FROM   tbl
ORDER  BY substring(issue, 1, 4) DESC
     , CASE 
          WHEN substring(issue, 6, 100) IN ('Winter','First_Quarter')  THEN 1
          WHEN substring(issue, 6, 100) IN ('Summer','Second_Quarter') THEN 2
          WHEN substring(issue, 6, 100) IN ('Spring','Third_Quarter')  THEN 3
          WHEN substring(issue, 6, 100) IN ('Fall',  'Fourth Quarter') THEN 4
          ELSE 5 
       END;
```

> `Winter -> Summer -> Spring` - it's what the client wants! :)

#### Optimize performance

A "simple" `CASE` should perform better since the expression is only evaluated once.
And `right(issue, -5)` is equivalent to `substring(issue, 6, 100)`, but a bit faster:

```sql
SELECT npid, title, url, issue
FROM   tbl
ORDER  BY left(issue, 4) DESC
     , CASE right(issue, -5)
          WHEN 'Winter'         THEN 1
          WHEN 'First_Quarter'  THEN 1
          WHEN 'Summer'         THEN 2
          WHEN 'Second_Quarter' THEN 2
          WHEN 'Spring'         THEN 3
          WHEN 'Third_Quarter'  THEN 3
          WHEN 'Fall'           THEN 4
          WHEN 'Fourth Quarter' THEN 4
          ELSE 5 
       END;
```

[`left()` and `right()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html) have been added with PostgreSQL 9.1. The trick with `right()` is to use a *negative number* to trim a constant number of characters from the left.

#### Syntax variants

This is equivalent (for strings of <= 100 characters):

```sql
SELECT substring(issue from 6 for 100) AS substring1
     , substring(issue, 6, 100)        AS substring2
     , substring(issue, 6)             AS substring3
     , substr(issue, 6, 100)           AS substr1
     , substr(issue, 6)                AS substr2
     , right(issue, -5)                AS right0
FROM   tbl;
```

[-> sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/d41d8/356)

Comment: Getting error: `Msg 174, Level 15, State 1, Line 15 - The substring function requires 3 argument(s).`

Comment: @marc_s: In some implementations the third argument for substring() is optional (like in PostgreSQL). I added one for you. Also changed to standard SQL syntax variant `from x for y`.

Comment: Sorry, yes - I was testing on SQL Server 2008 R2 and there the third parameter is required.

Comment: I'm getting "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'" for the "issue from 1 for 4" portion :(

Comment: @Brds: ok, now which DBMS are you using exactly? enough with the guesswork.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a variation of the same theme

```
ORDER BY
    SUBSTRING(issue,1,4) Desc,

CASE SUBSTRING(issue,6, LEN(issue) - 5)
   WHEN 'First_Quarter' THEN 1
   WHEN 'Second_Quarter' THEN 2
   WHEN 'Second_Quarter' THEN 3
   WHEN 'Winter' then 1
   WHEN 'Spring' then 2
   WHEN 'Summer' then 3
   WHEN 'Fall' then 4
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make the sub string part of the data being selected

```
SELECT npId, title, URL, issue, SUBSTRING(issue, 4) AS strsort FROM tbl ORDER BY strsort, issue
```

Comment: Missing a `FROM ....` clause, and getting error: `Msg 174, Level 15, State 1, Line 10 - The substring function requires 3 argument(s).`

Comment: You missed the bit about sub order of Quarters and seasons

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use if/then constructions anywhere in a sql command.

Do you already have a substring-pattern that works for you? if so, you can use something like:

```
ORDER BY (IF (SUBSTRING(first_match_of_issue) IS NOT NULL) THEN first_match_of_issue ELSE second_match_of_issue))
```

However - if you already know what they're going to be, then the CASE statements mentioned in other answers are probably easier.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach (this is in T-SQL):

```
select
        *
    from
        your_table as t
    order by
        substring([issue], 1, 4) desc,
        case substring([issue], 6, len([issue]) - 5)
            when 'First_Quarter' then 1
            when 'Second_Quarter' then 2
            when 'Third_Quarter' then 3
            when 'Fourth_quarter' then 4
            when 'Spring' then 3
            when 'Summer' then 2
            when 'Fall' then 4
            when 'Winter' then 1
            else 5 -- show unexpected input last
        end asc
```

Comment: And to be make it **really** work, it should be `CAST(SUBSTRING(issue, 1, 4) AS INT) DESC` so that it will be sorted **numerically** in a descending fashion .... (otherwise it will still be sorted as **strings** which is not necessarily the same sort order as a numerical sort)

Comment: @marc_s: Though you are, of course, quite correct, I think describing the approach in general is more valuable than a meticulously detailed copy and paste solution. And, in the real world, I don't know of a case when four-character strings of digits don't get sorted the same way as the equivalent integers. We're not likely to see any 3-digit or 5-digit years come out of this.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Column1, row_number() over(order by substring(column2,280,9)) 
FROM YourTable
```

This will give the `order by` of substring column2.