# How to give priority over one like statement in SQL

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql, search, sql-like

I am building a search box that queries a database and autofills suggestions below.

I want to be able to priorities the results in order of :

**1 - Exact match**

**2 - Starts with the same couple of letters**

**3 - Contains the string somewhere within the database**

I have a SQL statement

```
SELECT * 
FROM Products 
WHERE ProductName LIKE ? 
OR ProductName LIKE ? 
GROUP BY ProductName 
ORDER BY ProductName ASC 
LIMIT 10
```

In an example for searching for the word "computer"

When typing "co" it should show

- **co** -co
- **co** mputer
- **co** mputer desk
- ac **co** unt

but when furthering the search to "computer"

- **computer**
- **computer** deks

The first binding param contains %computer% and the second contains c%omputer%

Thanks for the help and if you need anything clarifying let me know.

Comment: how do you decide what gets priority?  just the longer string?  or...?

Comment: At the moment if I type "co" it would put account above computer because it is ORDER BY ASC but what I want it to do is show computer above account because I have typed "co" so anything starting with "co" should come above anything that just contains "co"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM Products WHERE ProductName = ? LIMIT 10 UNION
SELECT * FROM Products WHERE ProductName LIKE ? LIMIT 10 UNION
SELECT * FROM Products WHERE ProductName LIKE ? LIMIT 10
```

This works well, The first ? holds 'co' the second ? holds 'co%' and the third ? holds '%co%'

This prioritises the exact match first, then starting with the string and then containing the string.

Comment: I am using PHP, MySQL and JQuery. Should this still work? Could you explain what is going on?

Comment: you should tag your question appropiately in that case. Jimmy is doing c#

Comment: I'm not completely familiar with MySQL, so you may need to move the top 10 to that "limit 10" at the end (before the union), what's happening here is it executes the first query, then "union"s the second query to that (appends it to the end) then appends to the end of that the 3rd query. The first query gets equality, second gets starts with and then wildcard, 3rd gets wildcards on either side of the string. You could put this into a subquery and then trim it to 10 again, but 30 isn't a lot to push over the wire and subqueries are expensive on DBs

Comment: When I try this in PHP MyAdmin's SQL engine I get an error saying "#1054 - Unknown column 'Products.ProductName' in 'order clause'"

`SELECT * FROM Products WHERE ProductName = 'co' UNION
SELECT * FROM Products WHERE ProductName LIKE 'co%' UNION
SELECT * FROM Products WHERE ProductName LIKE '%co%' LIMIT 10`

Comment: @user1136076 Editted it may work I believe. If not, let me know and I'll delete this answer as I don't know MySQL

Answer (score 0):

Use a [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) in MYSQL to combine each separate query for your criteria. Have one super select that gives you the top 10.

```
select * 
from (
  -- exact macth
  SELECT 1 as prio, *  
  FROM Products  
  WHERE ProductName = ?  
  GROUP BY ProductName  
  ORDER BY ProductName ASC  
  LIMIT 10 
  UNION
  -- start with
  SELECT 2 as prio, *  
  FROM Products  
  WHERE ProductName LIKE ?*  
  GROUP BY ProductName  
  ORDER BY ProductName ASC  
  LIMIT 10 
  UNION
  -- anywhere -- 
  SELECT 3 as prio, *  
  FROM Products  
  WHERE ProductName LIKE *?*  
  GROUP BY ProductName  
  ORDER BY ProductName ASC  
  LIMIT 10 
)
ORDER BY prio, ProductName ASC  
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, could you explain or provide me with a link to understand what is going on :-)

Comment: Not knowing what sql dialect your using but what I basically whipped together is for each of your conditions a separate query that gets union-ed http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx and the final result is then sorted based on priority, productname and limited to maxium of 10

Answer (score 0):

No idea if this would work, since I'm no SQL-Guru and I've never ever used MySQL but if you look at this post

[SQL: ORDER BY using a substring within a specific column... possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187828/sql-order-by-using-a-substring-within-a-specific-column-possible)

maybe something like this would work:

```
ORDER BY
CAST(SUBSTRING(ProductName, 1, @ProductName.Count()) AS INT) DESC,  -- Year
CASE
    WHEN issue LIKE @productName THEN 1
    WHEN issue LIKE @productName + '%' THEN 2
    WHEN issue LIKE '%' + @productName THEN 3
END
LIMIT 10
```

Anyhow good luck and hope you solve the problem! Too late for me so going to bed, if it doesn't work I'll try too see if my brain works tomorrow and if you haven't already solved it :)