# Sorting by partial keyword match

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
        *
    FROM
        `Magic The Gathering`
    WHERE
        `set` =  'Magic 2013'
    ORDER BY
        FIELD (`rarity`, 'Mythic', 'Rare', 'Uncommon', 'Common', 'Land') ASC,
        FIELD (`type`, 'Planeswalker ', 'Creature', 'Instant', 'Sorcery', 'Enchantment', 'Artifact', 'Land') ASC
    LIMIT
        500
```

'Type' consists of a large variety of keywords such as 'Planeswalker - Ajani', 'Legendary Artifact', 'Creature - Elf Druid', etc.

How can I sort type so it's displayed based on partially matching keywords such as, 'Planeswalker ', 'Creature', 'Instant', 'Sorcery', 'Enchantment', 'Artifact', 'Land'?

Comment: Possible duplicate and solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187828/sql-order-by-using-a-substring-within-a-specific-column-possible

Comment: It seems to me that it would be a good idea to completely sidestep this and other possible problems entirely by introducing another column that simply stores the type of card, effectively one of the values you are trying to sort on.

Comment: I can't change the DB as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using a case statement and like:

```
Order by (case when type like '%Planeswalker%' then 1
            When ....
        end)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use  [`CASE WHEN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html) to solve your issue.

```
SELECT 
        *
    FROM
        `Magic The Gathering`
    WHERE
        `set` =  'Magic 2013'
    ORDER BY
        FIELD (`rarity`, 'Mythic', 'Rare', 'Uncommon', 'Common', 'Land') ASC,
        CASE
            WHEN `type` LIKE '%Planeswalker%' THEN 1
            WHEN `type` LIKE '%Creature%' THEN 2
            WHEN `type` LIKE '%Instant%' THEN 3
            -- ...

        END CASE
    LIMIT
        500
```