# MSSQL - does a CASE statement in an ORDER BY clause return column ordinals?

Tags: sql-server, sql-order-by, case

I ran across a suggestion here ([SQL: ORDER BY using a substring within a specific column... possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187828/sql-order-by-using-a-substring-within-a-specific-column-possible)) that shows a CASE statement returning integers inside an ORDER BY clause on a table with 4 columns.

```
SELECT npID, title, URL, issue
FROM   tbl
ORDER  BY substring(issue, 1, 4) DESC
      ,CASE 
          WHEN substring(issue, 6, 100) IN ('Winter','First_Quarter')  THEN 1
          WHEN substring(issue, 6, 100) IN ('Summer','Second_Quarter') THEN 2
          WHEN substring(issue, 6, 100) IN ('Spring','Third_Quarter')  THEN 3
          WHEN substring(issue, 6, 100) IN ('Fall',  'Fourth Quarter') THEN 4
          ELSE 5 
       END;
```

I do not understand how this works. Clearly the integers that result from the CASE are NOT column ordinals (for example, the ELSE 5, since the table has only 4 columns). But what do they mean? -- The context makes it seem as if they are to be used THEMSELVES for ordering on, but I've never seen this kind of thing in an ORDER BY. (However, the example given in the post works, so I am really perplexed.) Can someone explain what it means to return integers inside a CASE statement inside an ORDER BY clause? Thank you.

Comment: `ORDER BY` accepts a column list by name or ordinal *or* an expression - as in your `CASE` which is evaluated for each row in the result set, each evaluation returns an integer in the range 1 to 5 and that value is used as the sort key.

Comment: AlexK -- I still don't understand. You say "ordinal or an expression". How does the engine tell the difference between an ordinal (which, after all, IS an expression) and an "expression"?

Comment: If its a single integer literal like `5`, its an ordinal - thats the only way to specify one, `order by 1+1` / `order by @int_var` will both cause errors.

Comment: Looking at the sql-92 standard we can see the origin: *If a <sort specification> contains an <unsigned integer>,
              then the <unsigned integer> shall be greater than 0 and not
              greater than the degree of T. The <sort specification> iden              tifies the column of T with the ordinal position specified by
              the <unsigned integer>.*   (T = column count)

Comment: So presumably the internal parsing rules are - If its a col name order by that, if its an integer order by that col number else if its a non-constant scalar expression order by that.

Comment: Ah -- finally, what I was looking for. Thank you very much. How do I mark this as the "answer"?? since it only came in as a "comment?"

Comment: I've added an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only time an item in a `ORDER BY` clause is considered to be an ordinal is when its an integer literal, looking at the sql-92 standard we can see the origin of this:

> If a <sort specification> contains an <unsigned integer>, then the
>   <unsigned integer> shall be greater than 0 and not greater than the
>   degree of T. The <sort specification> identifies the column of T with
>   the ordinal position specified by the <unsigned integer>.

If the `ORDER BY` clause contains a non-constant scalar expression such as [`CASE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx#Case) then the result of that expression is used as the sort key, i.e. if it evaluates a row in the result set and returns an integer *n* it is the value of *n* that is sorted upon.

Answer (score 2):

These integers aren't column ordinals, but value literals. The query is first sorted by the first four characters of the `issue` column (representing the year). Then, they are ordered according to a secondary key represented by the the `case` expression. The values used there aren't interesting on their own right, only the relative order between them is important. E.g., `2`, calculated for summer issues has no meaning - only that it comes after winter (calculated as 1) and before spring (calculated as 3). The query could have used 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' and 'e' instead and got the exact same result.

Comment: Thank you, yes I see what is occurring. I am just shocked. I mean, why should CASE work one way in ORDER BY if it returns an integer and another way if it returns a columnname? ESPECIALLY since "normaly" an integer in an ORDER BY does make sense -- it means column ordinal. I'm not doubting -- only asking, where is this documented? And does it mean I CAN'T use CASE in an ORDER BY to return a column ordinal if I wanted to?

Comment: `case` **always** returns a value.  When it returns a column it just means it returns the **value** this row has for that column.

Comment: I don't think you understand why I am perplexed. I agree this is a cool way to establish order -- I just don't understand how CASE can be used like this -- isn't this totally different from the way CASE normally works?

Comment: So I understand Mureinik what you are saying. ORDER BY looks at a position and evaluates it. If it's a column name, it gets that value. If it's an integer from a CASE, it evaluates that. BUT WHAT ABOUT THE SITUATION WHERE JUST A NUMBER APPEARS? (I.e. an column ordinal). Isn't it awfully confusing that here the result of CASE is DIFFERENT that it usually is, where you simply take the result and plug it in at that spot. So ORDER BY 5 and ORDER BY [case statement returns 5] are not the same. Wouldn't it be more consistent to use the CASE in a returned column, then order on that column?

Answer (score 1):

The integer values present in `CASE` statement are not column ordinals those are static Integer values that will be used to order the result.

After ordering the records by `substring(issue, 1, 4) DESC`,

when `substring(issue, 6, 100)` is `'Winter'` or `'First_Quarter'` then it will be sorted first,

when `substring(issue, 6, 100)` is `'Summer'` or `'Second_Quarter'` then it will sort after `'Winter'` or `'First_Quarter'`

and so on..

For better understanding you can select the case and see the result

```
SELECT npID, title, URL, issue,CASE 
          WHEN substring(issue, 6, 100) IN ('Winter','First_Quarter')  THEN 1
          WHEN substring(issue, 6, 100) IN ('Summer','Second_Quarter') THEN 2
          WHEN substring(issue, 6, 100) IN ('Spring','Third_Quarter')  THEN 3
          WHEN substring(issue, 6, 100) IN ('Fall',  'Fourth Quarter') THEN 4
          ELSE 5 
       END
FROM   tbl
ORDER  BY substring(issue, 1, 4) DESC
      ,CASE 
          WHEN substring(issue, 6, 100) IN ('Winter','First_Quarter')  THEN 1
          WHEN substring(issue, 6, 100) IN ('Summer','Second_Quarter') THEN 2
          WHEN substring(issue, 6, 100) IN ('Spring','Third_Quarter')  THEN 3
          WHEN substring(issue, 6, 100) IN ('Fall',  'Fourth Quarter') THEN 4
          ELSE 5 
       END;
```

Comment: I kind of see what MUST be going on, but where is this documented? I thought the result of a CASE is simply put into the query, so you would have something like ORDER BY xyz,3 meaning order on column named xyz, then order on the 3rd resulting column. Since when can you just eject a value as if it was placed in a column? Is this just a special way CASE works inside of ORDER BY? Why isn't this documented wherever CASE is explained?

Comment: Furthermore I've seen other examples where a CASE statement DOES output a columnname -- obviously in that situation the meaning is that the result should be handled just as if the column name simply appeared in the ORDER BY. Why this special treatment for integers? Wouldn't it be more consistent to put the integer into a column in the SELECT, and then order on that column?

Comment: Look -- thank you very much for trying to explain. But I had already looked at that page and in fact it does NOT show an example where CASE is returning integers. It only shows case returning column names.

Comment: No, in the MSDN example `THEN BusinessEntityID END ` is *not* returning the name `BusinessEntityID` its returning the *value of* the `BusinessEntityID` on that row - which is an integer so the same as any integer - `THEN 42 END`

Comment: AlexK: but it's NOT the "same as any integer" is it? I mean, if you just put an integer in an ORDER BY it is taken to mean a column ordinal. Why in this one place does the result of a CASE not what you would expect if you simply substituted that value without having used the CASE? I've asked this question three times here and no one has addressed it.

Comment: @user1693404 `order by 1` is not same as `order by case when 1=1 then 1 else 2 end`. In first order by `1` will act as ordinal position but in second order by it is a value or a value inside a column

Answer (score 0):

> does a CASE statement in an ORDER BY clause return column ordinals?

No.

Below statement changes order in which the values appear in that column only

```
CASE 
          WHEN substring(issue, 6, 100) IN ('Winter','First_Quarter')  THEN 1
          WHEN substring(issue, 6, 100) IN ('Summer','Second_Quarter') THEN 2
          WHEN substring(issue, 6, 100) IN ('Spring','Third_Quarter')  THEN 3
          WHEN substring(issue, 6, 100) IN ('Fall',  'Fourth Quarter') THEN 4
          ELSE 5 
       END;*emphasized text*
```

Comment: I don't understand. In WHAT column only??